# Measuring time with a resolution of microseconds in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, timing

I'm looking for a way to measure microsecs in C++/Windows.

I read about the "clock" function, but it returns only milliseconds...
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(VS.85).aspx) and [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905(v=VS.85).aspx) for finest grain timing on Windows.

MSDN article on code timing with these APIs [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172338) (sample code is in VB - sorry).

Comment: I remember there being some issue about using those on multi-processor systems. Does remember what it is and if it was fixed?

Comment: @André - correct, YMMV if you have an SMP system that suffers from this.  Docs says "On a multiprocessor computer, it should not matter which processor is called. However, you can get different results on different processors due to bugs in the basic input/output system (BIOS) or the hardware abstraction layer (HAL)."

Comment: I don't think the documentation has been updated since multi-core processors came out.  Today the BIOS & HAL are independent of reading the TSC and TSC differences between cores.  You can use the APIC timer for checking TSC drift on older systems.

Answer (score 4):

There are two high-precision (100 ns resolution) clocks available in Windows:

- [`GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895(v=vs.85).aspx): 100ns resolution, synchronized to UTC
- [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx): 100ns resolution, *not* synchronized to UTC

**QueryPerformanceCounter** is independant of, and isn't synchronized to, any external time reference. It is useful for measuring absolute timespans.

**GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime** is synchronized. If your PC is in the process of speeding up, or slowing down, your clock to bring it gradually into sync with a time server, GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime will appropriately be slower or faster than absolute timespans.

The guidance is:

- if you need UTC synchronized timestamps, for use across multiple systems for example: use GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime
- if you only need absolute timespans: use QueryPerformanceCounter

### Bonus Reading

- [MSDN: Acquiring high-resolution time stamps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [MSDN: QueryPerformanceCounter function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [MSDN: GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [MSDN: GetSystemTimeAdjustment function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724394(v=vs.85).aspx) *(where you can see if Windows is currently running your clock faster or slower in order to catch up to current true UTC time)*

All kernel-level tracing infrastructure in Windows use QueryPerformanceCounter for measuring absolute timespans.

GetSystemTimeAsFileTime would be useful for something like logging.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html

altough

> Get the UTC time using a sub second resolution clock. On Unix systems this is implemented using GetTimeOfDay. On most Win32 platforms it is implemented using ftime. Win32 systems often do not achieve microsecond resolution via this API. If higher resolution is critical to your application test your platform to see the achieved resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's nothing wrong with the QuerPerformance* answer already given: the question was for a Windows-specific solution, and this is it. For a cross-platform C++ solution, I guess [boost::chrono](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/chrono.html) makes most sense. The Windows implementation uses the QuerPerformance* methods, and you immediately have a Linux and Mac solution too.

Answer (score 0):

More recent implementations can provide microsecond resolution timestamps on windows
with high accuracy. The joint use of system filetime and performance counter allows
such accuracies [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414359/micro-second-resolution-timestamps-on-windows/11373924#11373924) or also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414359/micro-second-resolution-timestamps-on-windows)

One of the recent implementations can be found at the [Windows Timestamp Project](http://www.windowstimestamp.com)

Answer (score 0):

(since no-one has mentioned a pure c++ approach yet),

as of c++11:

```
#include <chrono>
std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch())
```

gets you the number of microseconds since 1970-01-01, and a port of php's `microtime(true)` api would be

```
#include <chrono>
double microtime(){
    return (double(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count()) / double(1000000));
}
```

gets you the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 with microsecond precision